# Assign a method for didEndOnExit event of UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How do I programmatically assign a method (observer?) to the `didEndOnExit` event of a `UITextField` object?

This is easy enough to do in IB but I can't figure out how to do it in code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just figured it out...

```
[mytextField addTarget:self 
        action:@selector(methodToFire:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

Answer (score 5):

In your view controller implement the following method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

//do stuff

}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate in viewDidLoad or the initializer:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Uou have to make sure the delegate is set. Also the textField must resign first responder, which makes the keyboard disappear as a clue you have done it right.

Comment: What you posted maybe right, I don't know. However the code I posted above is more elegant and accomplishes exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think what I meant to say was that UITextField was created with the delegate pattern in mind (as most Apple Controls are). Your implementation is equally valid. However, if you need to add custom code at different points in the UITextField's life cycle, it make sense to just implement the required delegate methods in your custom view controller instance. You can find all supported methods in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol reference.

Comment: This is an old one, but the difference here is the "on exit" part. `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called when the field finishes editing, either from tapping the Return key in the keyboard or by tapping something else in the view. The `didEndOnExit` event only happens when using the Return key from the keyboard. It looks like `UITextFieldDelegate` lacks a method for this event.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone considering to use this target to make another textfield becomeFirstResponder to create a 'Next' button option that feels like you are 'tabbing' through textFields I would recommend using textFieldShouldReturn instead with code like this. Let me tell you it works so well you'll feel like you're riding a unicorn:

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if([textField isEqual:_textField1]){
        [_textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }else if([textField isEqual:_textField2]){
        [_textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```