# How can I set didEndOnExit in code rather than Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign a method for didEndOnExit event of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861550/assign-a-method-for-didendonexit-event-of-uitextfield)

How can I add didEndOnExit to a UITextField in pure code rather than IB?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm learning as I go along :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your talking about `textFieldDidEndEditing:` or `textFieldShouldReturn:`.  You would implement the method in your view controller, and set the text fields `delegate` to `self` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ....
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 25)];
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTextField];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == myTextField) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == myTextField) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ((myTextField.text.length + string.length) < 5) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then, in your header file in the `@interface` you can specify that you are a `UITextFieldDelegate` like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    // ....
    UITextField *myTextField;
    // ....
}

// Optionally, to make myTextField a property:
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *myTextField;

@end
```

[**UITextField Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)
[**UITextFieldDelegate Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

---

Edit (as per your comment, this should work):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ((myTextField.text.length + string.length) < 5) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Well the thing is, I need it to prevent the user from typing more than four characters into the UITextField so is there an easier way to do this rather than the way you have put (sorry! I thought this would work for me but realised that it won't) - also, can it all be in code with no link ups to IB? :-)

Comment: Sure, check my edit.  To do it without the IB, you would need to create a UITextField in something like `viewDidLoad`, then add it as a subview to `self.view`, and set its delegate property to `self`.

Comment: Doesn't work, I can still enter text even going past the four character limit :(

Comment: If you made the text field in the IB then you have to either connect it to an ivar/property of the view controller, or connect its `delegate` property to `File's Owner`.

Comment: Ah didn't add self delegate - works perfectly now - thanks! :D

Comment: Anytime @reddexuk.  Happy to help.